# Bind command to command output

Tags: macros

How can I bind the command to the output of another command, determined at the time the command is bound?

For example with the following code,

```
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\newcommand{\world}{\hello}
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world % outputs 'bar'
```

how can I modify the second line so that running `\world` after the third line executes will output `foo`?

Comment: `\let\world\hello`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That only works if there is a single layer of expansion, doesn't it? For example, after `\newcommand{\hi}{foo}
\newcommand{\hello}{\hi}
\let\world\hello
\renewcommand{\hi}{bar}`, `\world` will expand as `bar`.

Comment: Is there a way to redefine a macro created using `\let`?

Comment: @xsznix a macro defined with `\let` is exactly the same as one defined with `\newcommand` so `\renewcommand` will redefine it

Comment: What do you take for "output of a command", e.g., the output of `\hello`? The `\meaning` of `\hello`? The tokens that form the top-level-expansion of `\hello`? The tokens that form the complete expansion of `\hello`?  The boxes produced due to `\hello`? Some of the content of the .pdf-output-file? With `\let\world\hello` the macro `\world` will  have the meaning which `\hello` has at the time of performing the `\let`-assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As long as argument-processing and is not an issue, you can pass the top-level-expansion of `\hello` as definition-text to `\world`:

```
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\expandafter\world\expandafter}\expandafter{\hello}
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world % expands to "foo"
```

or

```
\newcommand\passfirsttosecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\expandafter\passfirsttosecond\expandafter{\hello}{\newcommand{\world}}
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world % expands to "foo"
```

Via `\let` you can assign `\world` the meaning of `\hello` at the time of performimng the `\let`-assignment:

```
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\newcommand\world{}% <- just to make sure an error-message
                   %     is raised in case \world is already defined.
\let\world=\hello
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world % expands to "foo"
```

If you need deeper levels of expansion, you can probably have the assignment for defining `\world` performed in terms of `\edef` or `\protected@edef`:

```
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\newcommand\world{}% <- just to make sure an error-message
                   %     is raised in case \world is already defined.
\edef\world{\hello}
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world % expands to "foo"
```

or

```
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\newcommand\world{}% <- just to make sure an error-message
                   %     is raised in case \world is already defined.
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \protected@edef\world{\hello}%
}%
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world % expands to "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shows two ways of achieving your aim: Version 1 uses `\let` as suggested by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) in the comments. Version 2 uses `\edef` which you should only use if you need to expand previous content as [T. Verron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9517/t-verron) noted in the comments. Both will output `foo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% Option 1: let
\newcommand{\hello}{foo}
\let\world\hello
\renewcommand{\hello}{bar}
\world

% Option 2: edef
\newcommand{\hi}{foo}
\newcommand{\Hello}{\hi}
\edef\world{\Hello}
\renewcommand{\hi}{bar}
\world
\end{document}
```